# issue with onNavigate in react-big-calendar it's re-render the calendar every time i use next or back

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-big-calendar

i use react-big-calendar and i want to get the date of when using navigation (next ,back) ,
every time i use it it's re-render the calendar ti the current month . what is the issue this is my code

```
  const [selectedMonth, setSelectedMonth] = useState<string>();


 const getStartAndEndDate = (date: Date) => {
  const firstDay = moment(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  const lastDay = moment(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  const fullMonth = firstDay + '_' + lastDay;
  return fullMonth;
};

 const onNavigate = useCallback((date: Date) => {
    const fullMonth = getStartAndEndDate(date);
    setSelectedMonth(fullMonth);
  }, []);

return(
<Calendar
          localizer={localizer}
          events={events}
          views={['month', 'agenda']}
          onNavigate={onNavigate}
          startAccessor="start"
          endAccessor="end"
          style={{ height: '600px', width: '100%' }}/>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution ,

i was putting check for the request if it's loading , so every-time the isLoading =true , the component re-render .

Comment: This answer isn't exactly helpful to others. Can you answer it fully?